# Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference when iterating over Array

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello i have this method:

```
    private function  findConnectedNodes(node:Node):Array{
    var test_node:Node;
    var surrounding_nodes:Array = [];
    for(var i:uint = 0;i <= nodes.length; i++){
        test_node = this.nodes[i]; // contains an array of Node objects

        if (test_node.row < node.row - 1 || test_node.row > node.row + 1) continue;
        if (test_node.column < node.column - 1 || test_node.column > node.column + 1) continue;
        surrounding_nodes.push(test_node)

    }
    return surrounding_nodes;

}
```

I am getting this error: `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.` This error is appearing on the if statement.

I think this is due to the test_node variable, as flex debug shows me that `test_node` is `NULL`. Not sure why this is, as you can clearly see I am assigning objects in the array to test_node.

If I change `test_node = this.nodes[i];` to `test_node = this.nodes[<enter a number>]` the program works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i <= nodes.length`

Shouldn't it be `i < nodes.length`? This way you'll get null node on last step.

Answer (score 1):

I'd firstly simplify and add efficiency to your loop by using `for each`:

```
private function _findConnectedNodes(node:Node):Array
{
    var surroundingNodes:Array = [];

    for each(var i:Node in nodes)
    {
        // i represents the node in your array for the current iteration

        if(i.row < node.row - 1 || i.row > node.row + 1) continue;
        if(i.column < node.column - 1 || i.column > node.column + 1) continue;

        surroundingNodes[surroundingNodes.length] = i;
    }

    return surroundingNodes;
}
```

This is also a good way to avoid over-iterating beyond the actual length of the array as mentioned in @alxx's answer which is giving you `null`; see:

```
trace(nodes[nodes.length]);
```